# How to override the response body of a redirect?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When using `Redirect::to` in Laravel using the `Redirect` facade (`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect`), there is a default body response body that is sent. Upon further inspection, I've determined that it originates from the `RedirectResponse` class which calls the `setTargetUrl` function in the Symfony namespace `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation`. How can I go about using custom markup in this response, without modifying a third party library?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Adam use custom markup in the response body - please see the `setTargetUrl` method here for the default markup that is returned: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php#L91

Comment: @mycellius Can you clarify what you are trying to do from a higher level? Are you doing a redirect() in a controller?

Comment: @hdifen yes, I'd like to perform a redirect to another link from a controller

Comment: You can always create a function that handles all your redirects and attach your custom markups on all redirects for you. All you have to do, is route all redirects to your custom redirect function.

Comment: @mycellius You shouldn't have to worry about that as the html that symfony builds never gets rendered. Are you doing something like `return Redirect::to('/')`?

Comment: @hdifen on a server with a lot of traffic it does matter - the server needs to respond with this default markup that is way larger than it needs to be, driving network costs up.

Comment: @mycellius Yes and no but thats beside the point. I'm still confused on why you need to edit this. The way that the symfony redirect function works is to redirect the page using  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=%1$s" />`.  The user never sees this as the timer is set to '0'.  I might be able to help more if you show me your controller.

Comment: @hdifen of course it drives cost up - serving 1B requests that have a 10KB response vs a 1KB response are not equivalent in terms of cost. There are no 'users' in this case - it's a server to server call, which is why it's un-needed - all that is needed is the 302 status code and the Location header, no fancy HTML markup stating "Redirecting to..." etc.

Comment: @mycellius You need to take dev time into account.  Using libraries is always going to have inefficiencies.  The power of libraries and frameworks comes by saving you time to work on real business problems.